# Angular Reactive Form | Binding with value instead of formControlName

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a reactive form with a form array in it (**tipsAndTricks** field):

```
updatePoiForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(75)]],
    tipsAndTricks: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('', [Validators.minLength(25), Validators.maxLength(2000)])]),
  }, { updateOn: 'submit' }
)
```

In the ngOnInit I add all the default values to my **tipsAndTricks** array:

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  formValues?.tipsAndTricks?.forEach((tipAndTrick) => {
    this.tipsAndTricks.push(this.fb.control(tipAndTrick.id, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(25), Validators.maxLength(2000)]))
  })
  ...
}
```

Then in the template I have a custom control value textarea:

```
<div class="container__all-fields" formArrayName="tipsAndTricks">
  <div class="container__field" *ngFor="let tipAndTrick of tipsAndTricks.controls; let i = index; let last = last">
    <custom-textarea [formControlName]="i"></custom-textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the type of a **tipAndTrick**:

```
export interface tipsAndTricksResponse {
  id: string
  tip: string
}
```

As you can see I'm only passing only the **tip** field to my custom-textarea. And it makes sense that my custom-textarea stays that way: It receives a string and emit a string.

But the problem is that when I submit my form I would like to send the **tip** but also the **id**.

So my question is: Is there a way to bind a value to a form control (in a form array) even though it's already binded with the formControlName (so I could send only the **tip** to my custom-textarea but still having the **tipsAndTricksResponse** in my form control) ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have an array of tipsAndTricksResponse and you want to have a form than can change the "tip" property of this array.

In your updatePoiForm you have a FormArray of FormControl:tipsAndTricks

So in submit you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform an array of values (the "tips") in an array of objects with "id" and "tip"

```
submit(form:FormGroup)
{
  const data=form.value.updatePoiForm.map((x:string,index:number)=>(
            {
              id:this.tipsAndTricksResponse[index].id,
              ip:x
            }
  ))
}
```

NOTE: You should declare the formArray "empty" else you have one element more in your formArray.

```
updatePoiForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(75)]],
    tipsAndTricks: this.fb.array([]), //<--see that simply use []
  }, { updateOn: 'submit' }
)
```

Comment: But the problem is that I'm passing only the tipAndTrick.id to my formControl so when I submit I only get back an array of strings

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You can pass the "tip" and then your FormArray is a FormArray of FormControls and you're changing the "tip" (or pass the "id" if you want to change the "id"). If you need change the "id" and the "tip", you need create a FromArray of **FormGroups**

Comment: I'm passing the tip to my textarea and I want it to stay that way (receive a string, emit a string). Because of that when I submit I only get back the tip. But I would like to get the tip and the id when I submit. So maybe there's a way to pass the tipsAndTricksResponse to my formControl and only the tip to my textarea. (Sorry this is a tricky situation to explain)